# ASP.Net Web API custom route not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following function in a PersonController class

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetBloggersNotFollowed")]
    public IQueryable<object> GetBloggersNotFollowed(int companyId)
    {
        return Uow.People.GetPeople().Select(p => new { p.Email, p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.PhoneNumber, p.Type, p.UserName, p.Country, p.Id });
    }
```

It is used to retrieve a list of people.

I call the function as so

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: "/api/person/GetBloggersNotFollowed/1" 
}).success(function (people) { 
     PersonModule.GetPeople(people); 
});
```

And i have declared a route in my `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I try to call the route in the browser i get an error

```
<Error>
 <Message>
  No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:1045/api/person/GetBloggersNotFollowed/1'.
  </Message>
  <MessageDetail>
       No action was found on the controller 'Person' that matches the request.
  </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I don't know here I went wrong. Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the parameter is important to the route matching.

You have named the parameter `id` in the route yet the method has it as `companyId`.

Either change `{id}` in the route to `{companyId}` or change `companyId` parameter to `id`.

Comment: @WesleySkeen you are welcome - Thanks for reporting back (p.s. please mark as accepted if it answered your question).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your your route to this one:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{companyId}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This answer complements Mark Jones' answer.

Comment: Sorry mate Mark got here first. Your answer would also of worked.

Comment: @WesleySkeen: No problems, sharing of knowledge is more important, isn't it?